# how to sign a json web token using .p8 file

Tags: java, jwt

I need to create a JWT for using Apple Mapkitjs. I have a secret key in a .p8 file. My backend is in java. I am trying to use auth0 to do this. But it says I have to use a key provider or key for ES256 algorithm. I tried the following but got an exception "PKCS8 not found"

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS8");
```

I am fairly new to java world. Could someone tell me how to create a key from .p8 file

Comment: These are the available type for KeyStore getInstance(). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyStore

Comment: Also, you can take help from this code base too. :) https://github.com/Mukit09/CertificateBasedAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use **PKCS8EncodedKeySpec**

[PKCS8EncodedKeySpec Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/PKCS8EncodedKeySpec.html)

[Some Codes](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec)

Comment: Please provide some context around your links. Just some links (that might be invalid tomorrow) is not a good answer. See also [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
    //remember to remove two lines below in your .p8 key before run code
    //-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    //-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    //begin create a key from .p8 file
    byte[] p8der = Files.readAllBytes(new File("/tmp/AuthKey_KeyId.p8").toPath());
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec priPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(new org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64().decode(p8der));
    PrivateKey appleKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC").generatePrivate(priPKCS8);
    //end create a key from .p8 file
    Map jwtHeader = new HashMap();
    jwtHeader.put("alg", "ES256");
    //addmore header
    JsonObject jwtPayload = new JsonObject();
    jwtPayload.addProperty("iss", "{{replace with your issuer ID}}");
    //addmore properties
    JsonArray scope = new JsonArray();
    scope.add("GET {{replace with your scope}}");
    jwtPayload.add("scope", scope);
    //begin signWithES256
    JwtBuilder jwtBuilder = Jwts.builder()
            .setHeader(jwtHeader)
            .setPayload(jwtPayload.toString())
            .signWith(
                    SignatureAlgorithm.ES256,
                    appleKey
            );
    String jws = jwtBuilder.compact();
    logger.info(jws);
```