# Apple new requirement of enabling account deletion

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift

As everyone is aware that Apple has a new requirement for apps with `Sign in with apple` option to enable the functionality of account deletion.
They have two main requirements

Step 1. Revoke user tokens

Step 2. Delete all data associated with this account

So, `Step 2` is clear and every developer is clear about this but I (and all of the other developers) have some complications/problems regarding step 1 which are stated below.

**Problem 1**: As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/revoke_tokens) we can use `https://appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke` to revoke the user token, but this API always responds with 200 even if your client_id is wrong. maybe it's for security reasons and we can verify the revoke of the token by accessing some information using it. Am I right about this?

**Problem 2**: I know that the max-age for `client_secret` JWT is 6 months. can we implement this token revoke process on the client-side (app) and after that hit backend for account data deletion request or the other way around?
or is it best to do this all in the backend after properly verifying the user account deletion request by requesting a secret code sent to the email of the user?

**Problem 3**: Is it better to create the `client_secret` for every new request of deletion? or we can use set the max age to 6 months without any security concerns?

PS: If you want more context regarding these above queries you can see below question.

[I can't delete the user logged in with apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415745/i-cant-delete-the-user-logged-in-with-apple)

[How to validate the apple revoke token api (appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke) successfully when handle delete account on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556424/how-to-validate-the-apple-revoke-token-api-appleid-apple-com-auth-revoke-succe)

[How can I find the desired client_id and client_secret values for the appleid.apple.com/auth/revoke endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476140/how-can-i-find-the-desired-client-id-and-client-secret-values-for-the-appleid-ap)

[How to make Apple Sign In Revoke Token POST Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72399534/how-to-make-apple-sign-in-revoke-token-post-request)

Comment: Problem 2 : No this should be done in a server, Problem 3: Yes every time, why have a 6 month token in the wild. Apple addresses JWT tokens in context with the new weather api [minute 9:36](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10003/) it is not done in app. JWT tokens can be easily read. Just paste one in JWT.io, the client side does not need this.

Comment: this link might help: [There is an answer on how to implement it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415814/where-i-get-from-ios-firebase-api-the-apple-revoke-tokens-endpoint-parameters-c)