# How to get access token to revoke for existing Sign in with Apple Users?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

We implemented Sign in with Apple a year ago and we never used an authorization code to get access and refresh tokens as we never needed that. We stored an identity token and a user identifier for our purpose and using these two we managed to do signup on our own server. Now the problem is

1. How I can get an access token without asking users to Sign in Again.
2. If I log out and sign in again I'm getting a new authorization code and when using this code I get an invalid grant error with an invalid token or token expired error message. So this option is also not working for me. I'm stuck here.

One thing I found is that If I manually go to settings and tap "Stop using App" after this we're getting an access token and refresh token in (https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token) API response using authorization code. This also works only the first time. Next time it doesn't work.

So my main problem is how I can get access code for existing users?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have to generate a refresh token using token_type_hint as refresh_token. using this token call to auth revoke as token_type_hint is access_token.

Comment: I didn't understand your point. Can you explain in more layman terms? My main problem was this - how I can get access code for existing users? We do not have access token stored into our database..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).